# Question regarding VSCode's "Network Connections" documentation

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy, settings

So I work behind a corporate network and, at the moment, VSCode's extension search feature doesn't work because it's blocked by our proxy. I'm in the middle of working with our network guys to get it whitelisted and had a question regarding the hostnames [listed in their documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network).

Namely, what each of the hostnames they tell you to whitelist does/which features need said hostname. Some of them are fairly self explanatory based on the name, but others are less clear. For convenience, here's the list of URLs along with a guess for their purpose:

[VSCode Proxy URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok37a.png)

I tried asking on the [/r/vscode subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/cnocgq/question_regarding_vscodes_network_connections/), but got no bites there. Since the GitHub issue tracker isn't for questions, I'm asking here.